# would like to retrieve 1 record from 2 different rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that has the columns and Rows (notice no D record for team id 2)

[image]

What I need is a query that will allow me to retrieve 1 record, for each team id, with column names based on the Type (O or D in this case) such as:

[image]

I have found a query which works, however it does not seem too efficient.  Also, I may in the future NEED to break down and have another record where a new standings type is added, such as "G" for Group.

```
SELECT  s.StandingsId,
    s.StandingsTypeId,
    s.TeamId,
    s.Wins,
    s.Losses,
    s.Ties,
    s.SortOrder,
    s.WinLossPct,
    (select
       ds.Wins
        FROM Standings AS ds
            WHERE ds.StandingsTypeId = 'D'
              AND ds.TeamId = s.TeamId) AS DivisionWins,
   (select
      ds.Losses
        FROM Standings AS ds
            WHERE ds.StandingsTypeId = 'D'
              AND ds.TeamId = s.TeamId) AS DivisionLosses,
   (select
      ds.Ties
        FROM Standings AS ds
            WHERE ds.StandingsTypeId = 'D'
              AND ds.TeamId = s.TeamId) AS DivisionTies,

   (select
      ds.WinLossPct
        FROM Standings AS ds
            WHERE ds.StandingsTypeId = 'D'
              AND ds.TeamId = s.TeamId) AS dWinLossPct,

    t.TeamName,
    t.ConferenceId,
    t.DivisionId,
    t.GroupId
  FROM Standings s

  LEFT JOIN Team t ON
            s.TeamId = t.TeamId 
   WHERE s.StandingsTypeId = 'O'
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple SELF JOIN  is all you need

```
SELECT o.id, 
       o.teamid, 
       o.wins   Owins, 
       o.losses olosses, 
       o.winpct owinpct, 
       d.wins   dwins, 
       d.losses dlossses, 
       d.winpct dwinpct 
FROM   standings o 
       LEFT JOIN standings d 
              ON o.teamid = d.teamid 
                AND d.type = 'D' 
WHERE o.type = 'O'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b4f9/4)

If you needed a new type G you add another left join and the new fields to the select

```
   LEFT JOIN standings g 
          ON o.teamid = g.teamid 
            AND g.type = 'G'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9bf03/3)

Comment: +1 it's good one, but it could give incorrect results if there's no record for some team with type = 'O' - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30527/3. On OP data it should work all right, though

Comment: O is overall so that shouldn't happen

Comment: ah see it. Actually it's strange, how team1 could have 1 win overall and 2 in division

Comment: @Roman But assuming it could then a full outer join would work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30527/4.

Comment: yes, but it's not easy to add new type to full outer join :P Anyway I think your answer should be accepted one in this particular case

Comment: This one works.  I attempted the inner join last night but had some issues with it..  Thanks.  Regarding the test data, I did update it to have better "real world" examples.  Not as many in the Divisions total than in the Overall.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to turn some rows into columns, like this.

```
select
    s.TeamId,
    max(case when s.Type = 'O' then s.Wins end) as OWins,
    max(case when s.Type = 'O' then s.Losses end) as OLosses,
    max(case when s.Type = 'O' then s.WinPCT end) as OWinPCT,
    max(case when s.Type = 'D' then s.Wins end) as DWins,
    max(case when s.Type = 'D' then s.Losses end) as DLosses,
    max(case when s.Type = 'D' then s.WinPCT end) as DWinPCT
from Standings as s
group by s.TeamId
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05d9b/2)</kbd>**

It's also looks like there's a typo in your second recordset - Team 1 has Dlosses = 2  in first record set and Dlosses = 1 in second.

Comment: I fixed the recordSet.  Thanks

Comment: it probably doesn't matter that much but if you want to match the OPs desired output you'll need  `max(case when s.Type = 'O' then s.ID end) as Id`

Comment: @ConradFrix yes, thanks, I'll add that, but I think the main goal of OP is to populate columns with wins/losses/...

Comment: This solution did bring back the record sets.  I used the solution from Conrad as I needed some information back from the Team so I just added a join to the team.  Thanks.

Comment: @DanO this types of queries is helpful if you don't know type for anchor record, you can easily join Team to it